# Asp.net button doesn't cause validation when postback disabled

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, postback, requiredfieldvalidator

I have a form on my page. And I want to use `RequiredFieldValidator` & `RegularExpressionValidator` to validate e-mail address.

Here is my code.

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubscribe" runat="server" CssClass="subscribe-textbox" placeholder="Your e-mail address"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Not valid e-mail address" ControlToValidate="txtSubscribe" CssClass="subscribe-form-error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
 <asp:RegularExpressionValidator  ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="*Not valid e-mail address" ControlToValidate="txtSubscribe" CssClass="subscribe-form-error" ValidationExpression="^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="subscribe-button" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="Subscribe(); return false;" />
```

I want to send email address on client side with ajax and get result on client side. And I want to use asp regex elements.

When I disable postback on button with `OnClientClick="Subscribe(); return false;"` this code, the validation propery is disabled.

How can I disable postback on button and make cause the validation?

Answer (score 0):

> onbutton client click it validate ,everything is correct,it goes to
>   server side code,here at the top of code,disable button and at the
>   bottom enable button.

I've ran into this problem many times before when using updatepanels.

I've found that if the field needs to be validated then you have to actually set `CausesValidation="true"` on the element for it to still work with updatepanels.

Hope this helps you out!

Answer (score 0):

Using Vignesh's answer:

`<asp:Button ID="btnSubscribe" runat="server" Text="" CssClass="subscribe-button" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="Subscribe(); return false;" CausesValidation="true" />`